# define an ACL by dynamically matching url and method type from a list file in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I need to be be able to define an ACL if the incoming request matches a particular url and method type defined in a file.

for eg.)

```
acl http_denied_request **match path and method type here**
http-request deny if http_denied_request
```

The url - method type combination can be fetched from the same or different files.

Comment: When you say "URL" do you really mean URL, or do you mean URI or perhaps just URI-path?  Is this supposed to be an exact string match or a regular expression match?  How would it be possible for method and URL to be in two different files, when they appear to be a tuple?  What have you tried?

Comment: I meant match a particular URI and exact match works for now. The use-case here is, I will be flagging a uri(say /hello) and a method type(say GET) as a combination and reject requests at haproxy itself. I have the control of writing this tuple information into a file which haproxy can read from. I mentioned single/separate files because I couldn't find any helpful resources which would allow me to compare 2 attributes for the same request from a single file and define a single ACL out of that.